# SQLAlchemy - select data associated with foreign key, NOT the foreign key itself

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two tables, Name and Person.

Name:

- id (int, primary key)
- name (varchar)

Person:

- id (int, primary key)
- name_id (int, foreign key->Name.id)

Assuming my models are set up with the foreign keys, if I run `Person.query.first().name_id`, this will return an integer. I want it to return the `name` varchar. Is this possible? Or is there something I can do to get the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Name(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text) # or varchar 

class Person(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('name.id'))

    _name = db.relationship('Name')

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name.name
```

Getting the actual name back could be done like this or with a select in the name function. I prefer this way with a property. You'll need to fill in the details with how you are using joins in the relationship and other details.

You could `@property` to`@hybrid_property` to get some neat functionality from SQLAlchemy. Of course, you need to use it effectively.